# Call non-const function on a const object

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, member-functions, const-correctness

I am reading C++ Primer 5th edition page 258. The question is, can a const object call its non-const member function, even if that member function does not modify its data?

Sales_data.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Sales_data {
    // data members
    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0.0;

    // memeber functions
    const std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
    double avg_price() const { // *
        if (units_sold) {
            return revenue / units_sold;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
};

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const Sales_data& data) {
    os << data.isbn() << " " << data.units_sold << " " << data.avg_price();
    return os;
}
```

use_Sales_data.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_data.h"
using  namespace std;

int main(){
    Sales_data data;
    data.bookNo = "CSAPP";
    data.units_sold = 2;
    data.revenue = 50;
    print(cout, data);
}
```

When I remove the `const` for function `avg_price`, then the code does not compile. But I think the function `avg_price()` does not modify the object. My guessing is that, in the parameter list of `print`, I declared `Sales_data` object as `const` and C++ does not allow const object to call its nonconst member function. Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.** Remember two things-

1. If the function is non-constant, it can only be called by a
   non-constant object.
2. If the function is constant, it can be called on any objects (I mean
   any constant or non-constant objects.)

**Reasons:**

1. If the function is non-constant, then the function is allowed to
   change values of the object on which it is being called. So the
   compiler doesn't allow to create this chance and prevent you to call
   a non-constant function on a constant object, as constant object
   means you cannot change anything of it anymore. So the compiler only
   allows you to call it on a non-constant object as this object can be
   modified.
2. If the function is constant itself, then it is promising that it
   won't change anything of the object on which it is being called. So
   the compiler doesn't care whether you are calling a constant
   function on a constant or non-constant object as the function itself
   is unable to change the object.